possible to change sub-shortcuts of basic tools like 'move' [bpy.ops.transform.translate]?
Hello Blender Community!
I'm an experienced 3D artist, and I am trying to switch to Blender completely now.
For this, I'm converting many tools I gathered from 3D Software like Maya/3DsMax or ZBrush into Blender Python code.
Do you know of any ability to change tool-context-sensitive sub-hotkeys like when the move tool is active and additionally pressing SHIFT enters precision mode?

If that's impossible, do any of you know how to crack open these standard-tools and modify them in code to create a new version, like my personalized move/transform tool?
Thank you very much in advance!
Kind regards,
Martin

Those would be inside its own category called Transform Modal Map which affects all transformation operations across all Blender editors.
You can find them in Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Transform Modal Map towards the end

Beware these cannot be modified by addons, though they can be changed programmatically with run-once scripts.

thank you very much! I've to say this is very cool :) I'm having a hard time with Blender coming from 7+years with Maya but I'm starting to like this more and more!
